# xpath: find element with attribute AND contains?

Tags: selenium, xpath

I am writing selenium tests, and I need to switch to an iframe with no id or name and which parent element contains variable id's (so not helpful.  Also, the `src` attribute has variable data in it as well, so I can't target it directly like `By.cssSelector("iframe[src='example']")`. I need an xpath selector that targets the src, but also that uses contains.  I am trying to learn how to build xpaths outside of Chrome's `Copy XPath` but I can't figure this one out.  Thanks for your help!  Here is the iframe html:

```
<iframe scrolling="auto" 
    src="/admin/catalog/manage_variants_in_product.jsp?productId=160502" 
    width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="no" 
    style="position:absolute; top:0px; left:0px;">
</iframe>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "contains" CSS selector might help here:

```
iframe[src*=manage_variants_in_product]
```

FYI, there are also `^=` and `$=` that mean "starts with" and "ends with" respectively.

Comment: Yup, that was it!  Perfect!  I looked around, and I read that there was no `contains` in cssSelectors, but it never occurred to me to think about wildcards.  Thanks a lot!

Comment: This reference has a lot of good info. https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#selectors

Answer (score 0):

The better way I would recommend to learn building xpath or csspath is  `Firepath` add-on of Firefox

First install Firebug in your Firefox browse and then install Firepath.

There you will get the efficient way to get the xpath or evaluate the xpath build by yourself

Comment: Firebug and other tools don't create efficient XPaths. It may be easy, but the end result is not good.

Comment: Last time I used it was a few years go, but it seemed pretty much identical to Chrome's inbuilt `Copy XPath` in the dev tools.  Which is really good for a quick grab, but not if you need something more intricate.

Comment: @kroe761, what about an xpath created by you and  have to check weather it is correct or not? I'm using Firepath for evaluating the xpath. How do you verify the same ?. Please let me know if you are using some other tool for this.