# XPath to SVG element?

Tags: html, xml, svg, xpath

Any idea which XPath leads to this:

```
<a class="sc-2wok21-1 hlSSAt">
<svg viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24"><path d="M14.707 6.293L20.414 12l-5.707 5.707-1.414-1.414L16.585 13H4v-2h12.585l-3.292-3.293 1.414-1.414z"
```

I'm trying things like `"//a[@class="sc-2wok21-1 hlSSAt"]/svg` or `//a[@class="sc-2wok21-1 hlSSAt"]/[local-name()=‚svg‘]` but nothing works.

Comment: Your first one looks nearly right, but I am not sure you can do `@class="sc-2wok21-1 hlSSAt"` - I wonder if you need two `@class` contains.

Comment: Maybe have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44028602

Comment: The key here is experimentation. Get `//a/svg` working first, then introduce one class contains, then see if you can do both. Use an online XPath "Fiddle" app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your second XPath is close in its recognition that `svg` is in a namespace.

Change

```
//a[@class="sc-2wok21-1 hlSSAt"]/[local-name()=‚svg‘]
```

to

```
//a[@class="sc-2wok21-1 hlSSAt"]/*[local-name()="svg"]
```

to select the `svg` element.

Alternatively, declare a namespace prefix and use it in the XPath rather than defeating namespaces with the `local-name()` hack.  See [How does XPath deal with XML namespaces?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40796231/290085)